# color java JSlider based on tick value

Tags: java, swing, colors, jslider

I want to have a JSlider with three kind of colors each one occupying a range of values(eg. 1 to 10 is green, 10 to 20 is yellow, 20 to 30 is red), how can this be implemented?

Comment: Do you want the background to have three stripes of color? Or do you want it to be colored one of the three colors based on the selected value?

Comment: @Russell Zahniser: I want the background to have three stripes of color, how can I make GradientPaint to do that to the background JPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Oops, for some reason I thought there was a `paintBackground()` method in JComponent. I guess you'd instead have to do `setOpaque(false)` (so that `super` doesn't paint the background) and then override `paintComponent()` like this:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   int w = getWidth();
   int h = getHeight();
   int x1 = w / 3;
   int x2 = w * 2 / 3;

   g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   g.fillRect(0, 0, x1, h)
   g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
   g.fillRect(x1, 0, x2 - x1, h)
   g.setColor(Color.RED);
   g.fillRect(x2, 0, w - x2, h)

   super.paintComponent();
}
```